# React приложение ( сортировка )

Tags: reactjs

Подскажите, как сделать чтобы при клике на элемент списка, он появлялся в строке 'Сортировка по'?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function Sort({ sortItems }) {
    const [activeItem, setActiveItem] = useState(null);
    const onSelectItem = sortItem => {
        setActiveItem(sortItem);
    };
    return (
        <div className='sort'>
            <div className='sort__label'>
                <svg
                    width='10'
                    height='6'
                    viewBox='0 0 10 6'
                    fill='none'
                    xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'
                >
                    <path
                        d='M10 5C10 5.16927 9.93815 5.31576 9.81445 5.43945C9.69075 5.56315 9.54427 5.625 9.375 5.625H0.625C0.455729 5.625 0.309245 5.56315 0.185547 5.43945C0.061849 5.31576 0 5.16927 0 5C0 4.83073 0.061849 4.68424 0.185547 4.56055L4.56055 0.185547C4.68424 0.061849 4.83073 0 5 0C5.16927 0 5.31576 0.061849 5.43945 0.185547L9.81445 4.56055C9.93815 4.68424 10 4.83073 10 5Z'
                        fill='#2C2C2C'
                    />
                </svg>
                <b>Сортировка по:</b>
                <span>{}</span>
            </div>
            <div className='sort__popup'>
                <ul>
                    {sortItems.map((name, sortItem) => (
                        <li
                            className={activeItem === sortItem ? 'active' : ''}
                            onClick={() => {
                                onSelectItem(sortItem);
                            }}
                            key={sortItem}
                        >
                            {name}
                        </li>
                    ))}
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Sort;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function Sort({ sortItems }) {
    const [activeItem, setActiveItem] = useState(null);
    const onSelectItem = sortItem => {
        setActiveItem(sortItem);
    };
    return (
        <div className='sort'>
            <div className='sort__label'>
                <svg
                    width='10'
                    height='6'
                    viewBox='0 0 10 6'
                    fill='none'
                    xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'
                >
                    <path
                        d='M10 5C10 5.16927 9.93815 5.31576 9.81445 5.43945C9.69075 5.56315 9.54427 5.625 9.375 5.625H0.625C0.455729 5.625 0.309245 5.56315 0.185547 5.43945C0.061849 5.31576 0 5.16927 0 5C0 4.83073 0.061849 4.68424 0.185547 4.56055L4.56055 0.185547C4.68424 0.061849 4.83073 0 5 0C5.16927 0 5.31576 0.061849 5.43945 0.185547L9.81445 4.56055C9.93815 4.68424 10 4.83073 10 5Z'
                        fill='#2C2C2C'
                    />
                </svg>
                <b>Сортировка по:</b>
                {!!activeItem && <span>{activeItem}</span>}
            </div>
            <div className='sort__popup'>
                <ul>
                    {sortItems.map((sortItem) => (
                        <li
                            className={activeItem === sortItem ? 'active' : ''}
                            onClick={() => {
                                onSelectItem(sortItem);
                            }}
                            key={sortItem}
                        >
                            {sortItem}
                        </li>
                    ))}
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Sort;
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но не работает, к сожалению(

Comment: Извините немного ошибся) Поправил

Comment: через activeItem я тоже пробовал изначально, но он отображает индекс (цифру элемента списка)

Comment: Спасибо что сказали про индекс) Поправил map) Просто не особо понятно что лежит в sortItems

Comment: в sortItems через пропсы в app передаю элементы списка, а если в map литерал объекта добавляю, то элементы не отображаются( извините, если отвлекаю вас))

Comment: Приложите пожалуйста пример sortItems

Comment: sortItems={['популярности','цене', 'алфавиту']}

Comment: Я исправил код, попробуйте еще раз

Comment: Супер! Благодарю)

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста) Не забывайте ставить + ответам)